# animate and pgfplots, variable in domain leads to "TeX capacity exceeded"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, animate, debugging, bugs

I'd love to animate a plot but the problem even appears on this simple minimum example.
It would be kind if someone could check if there is a programming error on my side or perhaps a bug involved.

I use pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) btw

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}{10}
        \multiframe{10}{rt=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,xmax=10]
        \addplot[domain=0:\rt] expression {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }   
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are starting with 0 and pgfplots doesn't like `\addplot[domain=0:0]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer the problem could be solved.
It has to be taken care of that the domain will never be 0:0

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}{10}
        \multiframe{10}{rt=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,xmax=10]
        \addplot[domain=0.01:\rt] expression {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }   
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```